# Apache Zeppelin error local jar not exist

Tags: apache-zeppelin

> java.lang.RuntimeException: Warning: Local jar
>   C:\Zeppelin\zeppelin-0.8.0-bin-all\bin\54480 does not exist, skipping.
>   Warning: Local jar C:\Zeppelin\zeppelin-0.8.0-bin-all\bin\10.10.10.122
>   does not exist, skipping. java.lang.ClassNotFoundException:
>   org.apache.zeppelin.interpreter.remote.RemoteInterpreterServer at
>   java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(URLClassLoader.java:381) at
>   java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:424) at
>   java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:357) at
>   java.lang.Class.forName0(Native Method) at
>   java.lang.Class.forName(Class.java:348) at
>   org.apache.spark.util.Utils$.classForName(Utils.scala:235) at
>   org.apache.spark.deploy.SparkSubmit$.org$apache$spark$deploy$SparkSubmit$$runMain(SparkSubmit.scala:836)
>   at
>   org.apache.spark.deploy.SparkSubmit$.doRunMain$1(SparkSubmit.scala:197)
>   at org.apache.spark.deploy.SparkSubmit$.submit(SparkSubmit.scala:227)
>   at org.apache.spark.deploy.SparkSubmit$.main(SparkSubmit.scala:136) at
>   org.apache.spark.deploy.SparkSubmit.main(SparkSubmit.scala) 2018-09-18
>   10:33:29 INFO ShutdownHookManager:54 - Shutdown hook called 2018-09-18
>   10:33:29 INFO ShutdownHookManager:54 - Deleting directory
>   C:\Users\Polichetti\AppData\Local\Temp\spark-e1cca18a-e05a-4539-b1b6-2f56a8ab27aa
>   at
>   org.apache.zeppelin.interpreter.remote.RemoteInterpreterManagedProcess.start(RemoteInterpreterManagedProcess.java:205)
>   at
>   org.apache.zeppelin.interpreter.ManagedInterpreterGroup.getOrCreateInterpreterProcess(ManagedInterpreterGroup.java:64)
>   at
>   org.apache.zeppelin.interpreter.remote.RemoteInterpreter.getOrCreateInterpreterProcess(RemoteInterpreter.java:111)
>   at
>   org.apache.zeppelin.interpreter.remote.RemoteInterpreter.internal_create(RemoteInterpreter.java:164)
>   at
>   org.apache.zeppelin.interpreter.remote.RemoteInterpreter.open(RemoteInterpreter.java:132)
>   at
>   org.apache.zeppelin.interpreter.remote.RemoteInterpreter.getFormType(RemoteInterpreter.java:299)
>   at org.apache.zeppelin.notebook.Paragraph.jobRun(Paragraph.java:407)
>   at org.apache.zeppelin.scheduler.Job.run(Job.java:188) at
>   org.apache.zeppelin.scheduler.RemoteScheduler$JobRunner.run(RemoteScheduler.java:307)
>   at
>   java.util.concurrent.Executors$RunnableAdapter.call(Executors.java:511)
>   at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:266) at
>   java.util.concurrent.ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor$ScheduledFutureTask.access$201(ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor.java:180)
>   at
>   java.util.concurrent.ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor$ScheduledFutureTask.run(ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor.java:293)
>   at
>   java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1149)
>   at
>   java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:624)
>   at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:748)

Answer (score 0):

Please James, this is not the way that Stackoverflow works... Do some research If you have an error log, and don't throw to here like trash.